# Inconsistent device and property labels with xinput

Tags: xinput

On Linux, I use `xinput set-prop` to enable tapping the touchpad to click. To find the relevant device id as well as property number, I use `xinput list-props`.

Unfortunately, I find that both the device id and property number are not consistent across sessions. After a reboot, I often need to reconfigure these manually.

I am wondering what the cause of this is, and how to deal with the issue in such a way that manual reconfiguration is not needed after every reboot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to handle this is to write your own `xorg.conf` file (or put a file in the subdirectory where `xorg.conf` parts are collected, if your distribution does it that way), and use the `InputClass` section to match your device using vendor and device id or other hardware identifiers, and then apply the `InputDevice` options that are also valid for the `InputClass` section to enable tapping on the touchpad, or whatever else you want to configure.

Careful, the option names can be slightly different from the `xinput` names, so look closely. Inspect `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` after (re-)starting the X server to see if it worked.

See `man xorg.conf` for options, or google for tutorials (there should be quite a few).

Comment: Thanks! The Arch Wiki was able to help me work out the details. https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Touchpad_Synaptics